# How to set a statusCode and specific message on Hapi ^18

Tags: hapi.js, hapi

In Hapi version 18, how to set a `statusCode` and a `message` as an answer for a request?

There's one way to set the statusCode that is the following way:

```
return h.response().code(201);
```

However, how to set the code and a specific message in the response?

I'd like to send a response with an object ({}) and the statusCode.

Answer (score 3):

return h.response("my message").code(201);

The `"my message"`could be replaced by an object for example. The `201` code could be replaced by any HTTP code